# Конфиг Jekyll для редиректа на GitHub Pages?

Tags: ruby, github, маршрутизация, github-pages, jekyll

Одностраничный сайт на `React`, роутинг из браузера через `React-router`.

Если перейти к примеру на страницу `/user/1/post/123` и перезагрузить браузер, то выкидывает на стандартную гитхабавскую заглушку *"404 There isn't a GitHub Pages site here."* так как запрашиваемого ресурса нет на сайте.

Можно создать в корне проекта свой файл *404.html* и в случае отсутствия запрашиваемого ресурса будет редиректить на свою заглушку.

> Вопрос. Как настроить `Jekyll` (конфиг? плагины?) на `GitHub Pages` чтобы при запросе на существующий ресурс возвращало запрашиваемый ресурс, в случае отсутствия запрашиваемого ресурса редиректило **не** на *404.html*, а на *index.html*.

Comment: Сейчас, на сайте самый простой вариант: содержание файла _404.html_ копирует содержание _index.html_. Но это не инженерный подход ))